# extract values from one data frame given two variables from another data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames similar to these

```
date = c("2014-07-06", "2014-07-07","2014-07-08") 
temp_0m = c(12, 11, 13) 
temp_1m = c(11, 9, 10) 
temp_2m = c(9, 9, 8) 
temp_3m = c(7, 7, 6) 
foo = data.frame(date, temp_0m, temp_1m, temp_2m, temp_3m)   

DATE = c("2014-07-06", "2014-07-06","2014-07-06","2014-07-07", "2014-07-07","2014-07-07","2014-07-08","2014-07-08","2014-07-08")
TIME = c("01:01:01", "10:02:02", "18:03:03","01:01:01", "10:02:02", "18:03:03","01:01:01", "10:02:02", "18:03:03")
depth = c(1.2, 2.3, 0.4, 1.5, 2.2, 3.4, 2.2, 1.2, 0.5)
bar = data.frame(DATE, TIME, depth)
```

I want to extract values (temperatures) from "foo" given the date and depths from "bar". As you can see I have multiple observation on each date in the "bar"-data frame and I would like each of these depth observation to be given the temp value from "foo" depending on depth and date.

The result I'm looking for with this example data would be the following:

```
#> NEWbar
#        DATE     TIME depth NEWtemp
#1 2014-07-06 01:01:01   1.2 11
#2 2014-07-06 10:02:02   2.3 9
#3 2014-07-06 18:03:03   0.4 12
#4 2014-07-07 01:01:01   1.5 9
#5 2014-07-07 10:02:02   2.2 9
#6 2014-07-07 18:03:03   3.4 7
#7 2014-07-08 01:01:01   2.2 8
#8 2014-07-08 10:02:02   1.2 10
#9 2014-07-08 18:03:03   0.5 13
```

My real data frames are a lot bigger than these so a minimum amount of manual work would be a good idea.

Comment: Could you please add the expected outcome? Do you just want those 4 columns added to the bar data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I am assuming that depth '0-1' corresponds to 'temp_0m', '1-2' to 'temp_1m' and so on...  We can take the `ceiling` of 'depth' column after merging the 'foo' and 'bar' datasets (common column is 'date').  If the 'temp' columns are in order, then we use the `ceiling` output as 'column' index, cbind it with `1:nrow` to extract the 'temp' elements based on row/column index.  Create a new column 'temp' in the merged dataset and subset the data to include only columns from 'bar'.

```
d1 <- merge(foo, bar)
d2 <- d1[grep('temp', names(d1))]
d1$temp <- d2[cbind(1:nrow(d2),ceiling(d1$depth))]
d1[c('date', 'depth', 'temp')]
#        date depth temp
#1 2014-07-06   1.2   11
#2 2014-07-07   2.3    9
#3 2014-07-08   0.4   13
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset

```
 colnames(foo)[1] <- 'DATE'
 d1 <- merge(foo, bar)
 d2 <- d1[grep('temp', names(d1))]
 d1$temp <- d2[cbind(1:nrow(d2), ceiling(d1$depth))]
 d1[c('DATE', 'TIME', 'depth', 'temp')]
 #        DATE     TIME depth temp
 #1 2014-07-06 01:01:01   1.2   11
 #2 2014-07-06 10:02:02   2.3    9
 #3 2014-07-06 18:03:03   0.4   12
 #4 2014-07-07 01:01:01   1.5    9
 #5 2014-07-07 10:02:02   2.2    9
 #6 2014-07-07 18:03:03   3.4    7
 #7 2014-07-08 01:01:01   2.2    8
 #8 2014-07-08 10:02:02   1.2   10
 #9 2014-07-08 18:03:03   0.5   13
```

Comment: With the example data I provided this did the job perfectly, thanks! However, when I tried it on my real data I noticed that my example data was a bit too much simplified. In my "bar"-data frame I have multiple depths on the same date. This code generate an error on my real data like this:
`> d1$temp <- d2[cbind(1:nrow(d2),ceiling(d1$depth))]
Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds`
It still produces one temperaturer for each date (with some NA's though), but I would like too keep all multiple observations for each date and get their corresponding temp. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JohanLeander You may need to update your post with a new example that mimic the original dataset and also the expected result (I guess people can get confused without an expected result easily).   I coded this based on the example you showed.

Comment: The post is now updated with new example data and also better explained expected result.

Comment: @JohanLeander I think the code works fine for your new dataset.  Updated the post

Comment: Yes, with some small adjustment in my real data it worked! Thank you @akrun

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
library(dplyr)
dplyr::left_join(x = bar, y = foo)
Joining by: "date"
        date depth temp_0m temp_1m temp_2m temp_3m
1 2014-07-06   1.2      12      11       9       7
2 2014-07-07   2.3      11       9       9       7
3 2014-07-08   0.4      13      10       8       6
```